# How to access the iteration values in ARM Output's?

Tags: azure

I'm working on ARM Templates. Actually, I have to deploy two resources at a time into my Azure account. For that, I used copyindex() concept with the help of following [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-multiple) and am able to deploy them successfully. Now am trying to display the names of deployed resources by using Output concept in ARM. But due to looping of resources deployment, its resulting in following error.

```
"DeploymentOutputEvaluationFailed",
"message": "Unable to evaluate template outputs: 'alertName'. Please see error details and deployment operations. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage details.",
"details": [
    {
        "code": "DeploymentOutputEvaluationFailed",
        "target": "alertName",
        "message": "The template output 'alertName' is not valid: The language expression property 'alertMetricType' can't be evaluated.."
    }
]
```

Could you please suggest me to "How to fetch the values of copyindex() looping as ARM Output session values"

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to reference it like this for example because you need to assemble anarray which you need to each of your template to take the output from the previous one and concat it with its own output then print the result.

```
  "parameters": {
        "state": {
            "value": []
        }
    }


    "parameters": {
        "state": {
            "value": "[reference(concat('loop', copyIndex())).outputs.state.value]"
        }
    }
```

then call it in output:

```
"outputs": {
    "state": {
        "type": "array",
        "value": "[concat(parameters('state'), array(stuff_out))]"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply @MdaEngineer. Can you give more information regarding this, I can't understand this